# Format an excell column as link (ClosedXML generated file)

Tags: closedxml

i generated an excel file with ClosedXML library

```
XLWorkbook wb = new XLWorkbook();
wb.Worksheets.Add(dt,"aaaaa");
wb.SaveAs("aaaa.xlsx");
```

one column of the datatable contains a link (a string with a valid url), the generated excel file doesn't show the columns as link but as a normal string.
How may i format this column in order to make possible click on it?

Comment: https://github.com/closedxml/closedxml/wiki/Using-Hyperlinks